# Change Apollo Client options for jwt token

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, apollo-client

I want to set up a token in my apollo client when the user logs in.

This is my index.js:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
        ssrMode: SERVER_MODE,
        cache: new InMemoryCache().restore(cache),
        link: createUploadLink({
            uri: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL,
            fetch: SERVER_MODE ? global.fetch : NetworkService.customFetch,
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + window.localStorage.access_token,
           }
        }),
        defaultOptions: NetworkService.defaultOptions,
    });

ReactDOM.render(
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <Router>
            <App client={client}/>
        </Router>
    </ApolloProvider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The thing is, when the app starts there is no token, so the client is initialized with token: null.

When the user logs in, I set the token but I somehow need to refresh my application to take in account the token.

The login function just saves the token in the localStorage after a successful login api call.

How should I approach this? Right now, I'm doing a full page reload after login to bypass this problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the `setContext` method as described there : http://dev.apollodata.com/react/auth.html#Header and it works fine !

```
static authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    // get the authentication token from local storage if it exists
    const token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');

    // return the headers to the context so httpLink can read them
    return {
        headers: {
            ...headers,
            authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
        }
    };
});

...

new ApolloClient({
    ssrMode: SERVER_MODE,
    cache: new InMemoryCache().restore(cache),
    link: ApolloLink.from([
        NetworkService.authLink,
        NetworkService.errorLink,
        NetworkService.uploadLink
    ]),
    defaultOptions: NetworkService.defaultOptions,
});
```